# When making a presentation, do I use "slides" or "foils"?

Tags: word-choice

Talks are often supported by presentations via a projector (with a [presentation program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_program) such as Powerpoint).
During the talk, there is often a sentence like "next slide/foil/screen please" or "on this slide/foil you see [...]".

In the past there were two techniques:

- output on [transparency/foils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_%28projection%29) and presentation via an overhead projector
- output on [slides (Reversal film)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_slide) and presentation via a slide projector

In my experience, most presenters use *slide* in their talks, but some use *foil*. [LaTeX-based presentation tools](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=slidecls) use also *slide* and *foil*.

I have the impression that British speakers prefer *foil*, and American ones prefer *slides*.

Is there any rule or is it an individual preference? Or should I use *screen* like *Next screen please*?

Comment: A simple 'next' is entirely adequate. Learning the tech's name and saying 'Might I have the next one, Joe?' (or jane or whatever) will lend you an I-say-to-one-go-and-he-goeth air of casual professionalism.

Comment: You're right about the U.S. preference. I almost always hear _slides_ here.

Comment: I have *never* heard "foil" in this context, and I used to work for a company that made those little infrared remote pointer/controller doohickeys. (US English, though, so maybe them folks across the pond are even stranger than I thought.)

Comment: @Martha *Foil* used to be the dominant form here in the  States.  Probably before your time, though.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't think I'm *that* young: college was almost two decades ago.

Comment: I believe the term came from the transparency box being marked "For Overhead Illumination" - Foil

Comment: I have never heard the term 'foils' in American English. It is transparencies or slides.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In British English, I've never heard the term *foils*, although I have heard the term

> *Overheads*  (meaning transparent sheets for showing on an *overhead projector*)

and

> *Acetates* (named after the clear plastic used in the overhead sheets).

British English speakers so far as I'm aware don't use the word *foils* in this context.

So whilst it might be worth being *aware* that some speakers might use the word *foils* meaning *slides*, as a learner you'd be well advised to prefer the more standard term *slides*.

In this context, *slides* can always be used in place of *foils* without loss of meaning, and will be clearer to a wider section of your audience.

Comment: I'd always heard overhead sheets called "transparencies".

Comment: I used acetates a-plenty for overhead projectors in the pre-Powerpoint era (and even in the early Powerpoint years as a backup). I always referred to them as slides. (BrE). At school, back in the 1970s, some teachers used rolls of clear film mounted on an OHP, and would just crank the handle to scroll to fresh space as they filled up the page. I think they may have been referred to as foils - I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 2):

*Foils* was a very common term for overhead transparencies some 25 years ago in the States, at least in the academic computing world.

Can’t say I’ve heard it for a while, though that doesn’t mean it’s never used any more.  If push came to shove, I’d say it might have something of an old-fashioned smell to it, not quite so old-fashioned as the smell of [freshly mimeographed copies](http://www.chattanoogan.com/2006/7/27/89955/Remembering-the-Ditto-and-Mimeograph.aspx) with their weird purple copies, but something of that order.

Comment: Purple was the result of the hectograph or ditto process.  Mimeograph copies in my experience were almost exclusively black.  (Cleaning all the ink out of a mimeograph machine was really difficult, so changing the ink color would have been a long and nasty job.)  All these methods were pretty smelly and dirty.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, you’re right — it was the purple one I was remembering.

Comment: See, I remember those purple dittoed copies (they stank to high heaven, too, at least when "fresh"), but before reading this question, I had never ever encountered the word "foils" in any context even remotely similar to this one.

Answer (score 1):

"Slide" is the current standard term in the USA.  For reference, go to Help in PowerPoint and search for "slide" and then for "foil".  There are lots of hits for the former, and no hits for the latter.

However, in many companies, the term "foil" is still used, even though the actual slide is 100% digital and never printed on any form of film.  Intel (where I work) is an example.  It seems as though the term "foil" is at least as common as "slide" at Intel.  I believe the term "foil" dates from at least 40 years ago, when overhead projectors were first introduced, and the transparencies used were a very thin sheet of film (cellulose acetate) held in a cardboard frame to keep them manageable.

Comment: The PowerPoint Menu option is Insert Slide.